# Evaluating a Lebesgue integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the Lebesgue integral $\int_\Omega \exp\left(-\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right) \,dx\,dy$, where $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Initially I tried re-writing the integral as $\int_\Omega \exp{|x|} \,dx$ and using the definition of the Lebesgue measure of a ball, I obtained $\pi t^2$.

However, this isn't really helpful. How can I write this integral so that I get a "real" answer (i.e. not in terms of $t$)?

Comment: In polar coordinates, this is $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\infty} r e^{-r} \, dr \, d\theta$, which is easily computable. I'm sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: I am well aware that the first fold in the integral is $\Gamma(2) = 1$. The difficulty for me here was using Lebesgue integration to determine the first fold in the integral.

Comment: The function is nice enough to use Riemann integration, using the comment of T Bongers.

Comment: In my case I have to use Lebesgue integration.

Comment: You know that if the Riemann integral over an interval $[a,b]$ exists then the Lebesgue integral also exists and is the same value as the Riemann integral. So when looking at $\int_0^{\infty} re^{-r} dr$ we have to be a bit careful. In the Riemann sense we can integrate $\int_0^s re^{-r} dr$ for each $s$ so through a monotone convergence theorem argument on $\int re^{-r} \chi_{[0,s]}$ we see that the Lebesgue integral of $\int_0^{\infty} re^{-r} dr$ will be the same as the Riemann one.